# envers avoid to create revision when many side changed

Tags: grails, hibernate-envers

i've a problem with envers in grails

suppose that i have two domain class User and Project, there is a one-to-many relationship between them which User is the owner side

my question is that, whenever i add a project to user : user.addToProjects(project) , envers creates for me a new revision of user, it's what i want to avoid.I try to do this

```
User{
  static hasMany = [projects : Project]
  @NotAudited
  HashSet<Project> getProjects(){
     return projects
  }
}

Project{
 static belongsTo = [user:User]

 }
```

but it doesn't work, because there is not a property named projects in User
someone has an idea ?

thanks

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: it seems not working, i just avoid using cascade save, and it works

Answer (score 0):

Set this `hibernate` property in `resources.groovy`.

```
beans = {
    System.setProperty('org.hibernate.envers.revision_on_collection_change', 'false')
}
```